# How to position PopOver Based on Element position?

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, popover

I am trying to show Bootstrap popover for Menu in my ASP.Net core Application. I set the placement property to right. Bootstrap is showing the popover on the right-side perfectly. But I need popover's left top corner should be on the element's Right top corner.

Can anyone advise me to get fixed?

```
$(".menupopoverblock").popover({
          trigger: "manual", html: true, animation: false, container: 'body', placement: 'right',
          content: function () {
              return $(".popContentclass", this).html();
          }
      })
```

I tested with **position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right top' }** in several combinations, but there is no luck.

[Popover Image and Marked the Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwbY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You cannot fine tune popover with `placement: 'right'`. Looks like a function can be used: *When a function is used to determine the placement, it is called with the popover DOM node as its first argument and the triggering element DOM node as its second. The this context is set to the popover instance.*

Comment: Could you please give me a working example to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I am uinable to do so currently. Please update your post and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example